# change input value with change in select menu options

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

This is javacript for getting same category_name in input box as in select box
but i dont know the code for getting my category_id and category_desc for the same

`<script type="text/javascript">
            function filltxtbox(){
                var e = document.getElementById("sel");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                document.getElementById("txtselname").value=strUser;
                document.getElementById(defcatid).value
            }
        </script>`

This is the jsp page's code with which i set the default values but i want these values to change a s the select option value changes, if u need any other information please let me know.

```
                <%! Connection con = null;%>
                <%! Statement st = null;%>
                <%! ResultSet rs = null;%> 
                <%
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/mydb1", "mydb", "mydb");
                    st = con.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT category_id, category_name FROM Category");
                    con.setAutoCommit(false);
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        CATEGORY NAME
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%-- using select tag  --%>
                        <select id="sel" onchange="filltxtbox()">
                            <%
                                String catname = null;
                                int catid = 0;
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                    catname = rs.getString(2);
                                    catid = rs.getInt(1);
                                    out.println("<option value=" + catid + ">" + catname + "</option>");
                                }
                            %>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <jsp:setProperty name="category" property="*"/>
                    <%--// category_id input  --%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        CATEGORY ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%  rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT category_id FROM Category");
                            if (rs.next()) {
                                int defcatid = rs.getInt(1);
                                out.print("<input  type = 'text' name = 'category_id' id='txtselid' value ='" + defcatid + "' size = '30'/>  ");
                            }
                        %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <%--// category_name input  --%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        CATEGORY NAME
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%  rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT category_name FROM Category");
                            if (rs.next()) {
                                String defcatname = rs.getString(1);
                                out.print("<input  type = 'text' name = 'category_name' id='txtselname' value ='" + defcatname + "' size = '30'/>  ");
                            }
                        %></td>
                </tr>

                <%--// category_desc input  --%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        CATEGORY DESCRIPTION
                    </td>
                    <td><%
                        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT category_desc FROM category");
                        if (rs.next()) {
                   String defcatdesc = rs.getString(1);
                   out.print("<textarea name='category_desc' rows='10' cols='50' >" +defcatdesc + "</textarea>");
```

}%>`

Comment: can u explain clearly.You want to populate select box selected option in textbox?

Comment: i want to change my default input text value corresponding to a change in select box option. The value of input textbox should dynamically change with change in select box.
For ex: after we run the file, if the category_name in the select element changes so should the corresponding category_id and category_desc change in the input text area.

Comment: how many text boxes you have 2 or 1?

Comment: actually i have 7 text boxes but if i will get the code for category_desc, i suppose i will be able to get the rest of them..

Answer (score 0):

call this method using `onChange()` for select box.

```
function filltxtbox(){ 
   document.getElementById("textBoxId").value = 
   document.getElementById("selectBoxId").options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  }
```

`document.getElementById("selectBoxId").options[e.selectedIndex].text`  this will give the selected test(i.e category_desc)

Comment: well its working for category_id because i had set the select option tag's value attribute as my category_id.This is why i even asked for category_desc code ..

Comment: from where category_desc  will come

Comment: actually the text function would return the category_name and not the category_desc..(this is what i used for category_name)

Comment: where category_desc is available

Comment: actually these are being retrieved from a database, as you can see i used ResultSets to retrieve the values. category_desc and is another column in the database.

Comment: `<tr>
                        <td>
                            CATEGORY DESCRIPTION
                        </td>
                        <td><%
                            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT category_desc FROM category");
                            if (rs.next()) {
                                String defcatdesc = rs.getString(1);
out.print("<textarea name='category_desc' rows='10' cols='50' >" + defcatdesc + "</textarea>");
                            }%></td>
</tr>`
is the code for retrieving and making a text area for category_desc